# How can I calculate $\int_0^{45}{700(1.03)^te^{0.06t}}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int_0^{45}{700(1.03)^te^{0.06t}}dt$

I found that i can't solve it by integral by part.
How can i calculate it ? 
Thanks for help

Comment: Hint:  $a^x=e^{x\ln\,a}$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Note that $$1.03^t=e^{t\ln1.03}$$

Alternatively, we have$$1.03^te^{0.06t}=(1.03\cdot e^{0.06})^t\approx 1.094^t$$

Comment: +1: I prefer the first hint as $e^{(0.06+\ln 1.03)t}$ is easier to integrate  than $1.094^t$